# Python/Selenium click on <div class="foo'>

Tags: python, html, selenium

I try to use Selenium click() method:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class('foo').click()
```

on html tag:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo').click()
```

or

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="foo"]').click()
```

Comment: Note that `elem` would be `None` in this case.

Comment: Yes, if other operations with `elem` required better to split it into two lines: `elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo')` and `elem.click()`