# How do I click the label element with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to click the label but my code does not work.
How should I correct my code to work?

My code

```py
elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="071b5fe1-9d03-11ec-996d-47b2e9c07771_label"]).click()
```

HTML of webpage I want to crawl

```html
<label for="071b11c0-9d03-11ec-996d-47b2e9c07771" class="form-selector-label" id="071b11c0-9d03-11ec-996d-47b2e9c07771_label"><span class="row"><span class="form-selector-left-col column large-6"><span class="form-selector-title"><span class="as-chicklets-wrap" role="text">
    <span class="as-dimension-chicklets" aria-hidden="true">iPhone 13 Pro</span>
    <span class="as-tabnav-text">iPhone 13 Pro</span>
</span>
     
<span>6.1-inch display¹</span></span></span><span class="form-selector-right-col column large-6"><span> <span class="price-point price-point-fullPrice">From <span class="nowrap">HK$8,499</span></span></span></span></span></label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Selenium click on <div class="foo'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510666/python-selenium-click-on-div-class-foo)

Answer (score 1):

This can help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510666/python-selenium-click-on-div-class-foo)

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-selector-label').click()

elem = driver.findElement(By.id("071b11c0-9d03-11ec-996d-47b2e9c07771_label")).click();
```

Comment: @Tom You can mark this as the accepted answer so it will be removed from the "Unresolved" tag.